# Delphi: How to know when a TEdit changes size?

Tags: windows, delphi, events, resize, editbox

i need to update items around an edit box when it changes size.

TEdit has no **OnResize** event.

An edit box can resize at various times, e.g.:

- changing width/height in code
- form scaled for DPI scaling
- font changed

And i'm sure others i don't know about.

i need a single event to know when an edit box has changed its size. Is there a Windows message i can subclass the edit box for and grab?

Comment: You want to fire the OnResize when you change the code? How is that?

Comment: @Havenard: Ian means if the size changes in code at runtime, not if he actually changes the code at design time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OnResize is declared as a protected property of TControl.  You could expose it using a so-called "cracker" class.  It's a bit of a hack, though.

```
type
  TControlCracker = class(TControl);
```

...

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TControlCracker(Edit1).OnResize := MyEditResize;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyEditResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Edit1.Width));
end;
```

Comment: Most elegant, and shows off leaky abstraction flaws in most OO libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like this:

```
unit _MM_Copy_Buffer_;

interface

type
  TMyEdit = class(TCustomEdit)
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyEdit.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
  if not (csLoading in ComponentState) then
  begin
    // react on new size
  end;
end;

end.
```

or this:

```
unit _MM_Copy_Buffer_;

interface

type
  TCustomComboEdit = class(TCustomMaskEdit)
  private
    procedure WMSize(var Message: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
  end;

implementation

procedure TCustomComboEdit.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
begin
  inherited;
  if not (csLoading in ComponentState) then
  begin
    // react on new size
  end;
  UpdateBtnBounds;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the [`wm_Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632646.aspx) message. Subclass a control by assigning a new value to its [`WindowProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.WindowProc) property; be sure to store the old value so you can delegate other messages there.

See also: [`wm_WindowPosChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632652.aspx)